# How to prevent duplicating DB insertions when refreshing?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very new to PHP. I've tried to find an answer here that will fit my code, but I didn't find any.

When I press F5, the last insertion from the form duplicates itself in the database. How do I prevent it without redirecting to another page?

I saw a few answers about `$_SESSION`, but I did not understand how to use it.
I would love to have some explanation with the correction code, thank you.

PS, the db connection is in another file, if you need it to answer me, I'll put it.

Here's my code:

addToMembersList.php

```
<DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php
      include_once "db_connect.php";

      $member=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from members");
    ?>
    <style>
      table,tr,td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>First name</b></td>
        <td><b>Last name</b></td>
        <td><b>Email</b></td>
        <td><b>Website</b></td>
        <td><b>Comment</b></td>
        <td><b>Gender</b></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
        if($member){
          while($row = $member->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo '<a href="'.$row['website'].'">'.$row['website'].'</a>';?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['comment'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
              <td><button type="submit" onclick="deleteMember.php" value="$row['id']">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          <?php }
        }?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>



$query = "insert into members (first_name, last_name, email, website, comment, gender) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
      $query = sprintf($query,$_POST['fName'], $_POST['lName'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST[$gender_select]);
      $result = $mysqli ->query($query);
    }
  }

?>
```

index.php

```
<DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      function loadmembersList(response,textStatus,jqXHR){
        request = $.ajax({
        url:"memberListRequest.php",
        type:"get"
        })
        request.done(function(response,textStatus,jqXHR){
          $("#member_list").html(response);
        });
      }
      $( document ).ready(loadmembersList);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="", method="POST">
      First name:<input type="text" name="fName">
      <br>
      Last name:<input type="text" name="lName">
      <br>
      Email:<input type="text" name="email">
      <br>
      Website:<input type="text" name="website">
      <br>
      Comment:<input type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="your text here">
      <br>
      Gender:<input type="radio" name="Male"> Male <input type="radio" 
name="Female"> Female <input type="radio" name="Other"> Other
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="member_list"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, `<DOCTYPE html5>` is missing a `!` for it. Now, if you want to avoid duplication, there are too many ways to do/fix this and you can Google it. There are many results, I am 100% sure of it.

Comment: The solution is to not let the client sit on that page. Issue a 302 to a separate status/confirmation page.

Comment: `<input type="textarea"` that's not a valid input type.

Comment: `</html>



$quary = "insert into members` unknown if you opened the php tag here. Too many errors. Edit: `<form action="",` yeah... ok.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: You say "_here's me code- addToMembersList.php_". Shouldn't it be `memberListRequest.php`?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Why is that insert code always firing? Normally that's gated behind logic that tests if the parameters are present via POST.

Comment: as i said, i'm new to php. Thank you for your comments, but i'd like you to answear the question i asked... I've already googled it, but i couldn't figure it out. aendeerei you are right.

Comment: @tadman What do you mean?

Comment: I mean you'd have code like `if (isset($_POST['lName']))` or something like that which would test if a form has been submitted. This code runs *every time*.

Comment: Please explain better "_How do I prevent it without redirecting to another page?_".

Comment: Note that if you were using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to implement this you'd have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between. I'd strongly recommend you try at least one.

Comment: From what I understand your question: On each refresh the `$( document ).ready()` is called. therefore also `loadmembersList()`. Therefore the ajax is started. E.g. the scripts in `memberListRequest.php`. E.g the `INSERT` query as well. Your code should be structured in another way.

Comment: If you keep your actual code, in order to avoid inserting a record each time a simple refresh takes place, you should apply a condition around `INSERT` query: _Only if the form was submitted, e.g. only if the submit button was clicked, then insert record_. Example: `if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])){ // Insert record }`.

Comment: I think you can use isset to check if inputs are submited. But You must after each insert empty $_POST variable. So that when you check with isset it wont find anything.

Answer (score 2):

The common solution is to use a post-redirect-get pattern. The form collecting data from the user posts to a script which does the db operation then responds with a 302 redirect to a page which shows the outcome. The downside of this is that it requires at least 2 consecutive round trips to the server to navigate to the next page.

As others have noted, your code is subject to [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), but given the behaviour you describe, it is also vulnerable to [cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). A csrf token could be used to detect duplicate submissions.

Setting a suitable primary key /unique index and ignoring duplicate submissions would prevent duplicate records being created.

It is also possible to set a flag inside the form when the users hits the submit button using javascript. Then only carry out the insert if the flag is set in the parameters - but don't forget to plan for cases where javascript is disabled.

Another solution would be to send the data serverside in an ajax request rather than as a page navigation event.

There are probably more solutions.